# How to debug the issue Unable to install the app from APK in Android

Tags: android

I have an Android Application.

My QA reported that when they try to deploy the Build APKs in various emulators, the apk is not getting installed in OS versions less than 4.3.3. 
However, it's installing properly in any Emulator or device with versions greater than 4.3.3

But to try and debug this issue, I ran the application from "Android Studio" on the emulators of version less than 4.3.3, But the application gets deployed properly.

Does this mean it's not a programming issue, but a build file or packaging issue?

Here's my gradle snippet

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.intuit.qm2014'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
}
```

How to debug/fix these type of issues?

Comment: What is the minSdkVersion for that app?

Comment: @Logain - minSdkVersion is 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that there was a mistake in my build.sh script which our Jenkins Job was executing to create builds.
I had to fix the build.sh file to fix the signing to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install on problem devices with command

> adb install path_to_apk

and see output.

Also see logcat output on problem devices (possibly filter with tag "Package Manager") and you'll see some info about installation failed.

Answer (score -1):

Check your minsdk and targetsdk in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
```

This is just sample to check, place your appropriate values sdk version.